# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'combos.txt'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un problema que no consigo sacar... Estoy trabajando en un subprocesos de un programa más grande (una opción de un menú, pero para hacerlo más organizado, pensé en utilizar subprocesos.) El caso, este módulo cada vez que trata de poner el archivo de texto, me dice que no existe, cuando se encuentra dentro de la misma ruta que dicho módulo! Se que python trabaja con rutas absolutas si no recuerdo mal, pero en este caso, estaría bien que el usuario no tuviese que escribir toda la ruta.. Dejo el código por si es de ayuda:

```
#IMPORTS
import os
import platform
import time

if platform.system() == "Windows":
    clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
    clear()

print("You selected module five -> Lowercase first character in password\n")
time.sleep(1)

combo = input("Open your file: ") #USUARIO PONE NOMBRE DE ARCHIVO QUE SE ENCUENTRA EN LA MISMA RUTA QUE DICHO MÓDULO

if combo == "combos.txt": #EL USUARIO ESCRIBIRÁ EL NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO, QUE DEBERÁ LLAMARSE IGUAL QUE EL ARCHIVO QUE DEBE SER EDITADPO "combos.txt"
    try:
        verify = open(combo, "r")
        print("File was loaded succesfully!")
    except:
        print("--Something went wrong while trying to load your file--")
    
    with open(combo, "r") as f:
        prueba = list(map(str.lower, f.readlines()))
else:
    print("This is not the correct file. Please check another time.")
```

Dicho módulo también tiene otro problema más abajo, para los más observadores, puede que se hayan dado cuenta de que quizás el funcionamiento del lower no funciona correctamente. He probado distintas opciones en un archivo aparte pero no funciona. Por no alargar más el post, tengo dos problemas que me no consigo solucionar:

1. Cuando trata de editar el archivo no logra editarlo haciendo en minúsculas el contenido de dicho archivo (combos.txt).

Espero haberme explicado con claridad! =)
Cualquier duda o comentario siempre es bien recibido!

Intentaré estar atento a las respuestas ;)

Edit: El código lo he cambiado un poco a raíz de la contestación de Diego, aún así continuo teniendo el problemilla de arriba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método `lower` no te funciona porque no has leido ningún string del archivo hasta ese punto, lo que tienes en verify es un wrapper que te permite acceder al contenido del archivo, pero tienes que usar otros métodos como `read` o `readlines` para accederlo y luego aplicar lower a todo el contenido.

```
with open(combo, 'r') as f:

    # usando read, creo que esta forma es la mejor
    prueba = f.read()
    prueba = prueba.lower()

    # usando map
    prueba = list(map(str.lower, f.readlines()))

    # usando list-comprehension
    prueba = [line.lower() for line in f.readlines()]
```

Si quieres guardar los cambios en el archivo `combos.txt` debes abrir el archivo nuevamente en modo de escritura `w` y escribir el contenido.

```
with open(combo, 'w') as f:
    f.write(verify)
```

---

Ahora, este script que usas SI encuentra el archivo `combos.txt` cuando están en la misma carpeta, pero como dices que es un subproceso puede que python está buscando el archivo en la raiz de donde se lanzó el proceso principal.

Puedes verificar esto usando `os` y mirando en qué directorio está buscando python

```
import os
os.path.realpath('.')
```

Comment: Hola diego, muchísimas gracias por contestar! =) el problema ahora es que me dice que la variable "lower" no está definida (línea que viene después del comentario usando map). Como lo arreglo? Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Hola Diego! He editado el post con el código actualizado, por si te puede servir, he estado haciendo pruebas pero no logro arreglarlo

Comment: vale, ya hice unas correcciones al código, que por cierto te muestro 2 formas de hacerlo una con map y la otra con list-comprehension, usa una sola de las dos, y revisa cual te parece mejor, no solo copy-pegue sin leer

Comment: Hola Diego! He probado ambos métodos, y continua sin funcionar... Actualizo código, aunque no lo veo error... por cierto, no pego cosas sin leer, trato de entender cada cosa que hago, pero como persona, también me equivoco ;). Un saludo!

Comment: vale, disculpame por eso, ahora...he modificado la respuesta para añadir otro método y para que los cambios queden guardados en archivo

Comment: Hola Diego! Mersi por la respuesta! Me ha funcionado! =) Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda ;)